# Type Error Python

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

I am currently working on a game and I tried to make an image move and I keep getting this error right here

```
TypeError: unbound method put_here() must be called with create_entity instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

Here is the code for the PlayerEntity.py file the I made.

```
class create_entity:
    def __init__(self, image, name, armor, skills, weapons):
        self.entity_image = image
        self.entity_name = name
        self.entity_armor = armor
        self.entity_skills = skills
        self.entity_weapons = weapons

    def put_here(self,x,y):
        screen.blit(self.entity_image, (x,y))
```

Now here is the main Game file that I was testing this in

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import PlayerEntity as p_entity
    p_entity.create_entity('test_img.png', 'Default', [], [], [])
    p_entity.create_entity.put_here(300,300)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the instantiated object into a variable and use it to call its function:

```
entity = p_entity.create_entity('test_img.png', 'Default', [], [], [])
entity.put_here(300,300)
```

This code assumes that `import PlayerEntity as p_entity` returns a module `p_entity` that contains the class `create_entity` ([bad name for a class](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) - by the way)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is why I love Stack Overflow. I learn something new everyday.

Comment: Oh yeah I know the name for the class is bad, I was just testing some stuff out. I add random names sometimes just to test things out.

Comment: @SourceCoder I assumed from your nick that you should know it ;)

Comment: I wish, I'm only 14, I'm still trying to master this, especially since I'm not learning from books or from a teacher.

Comment: @Stormy 14 is an excellent age to start! and you can find almost anything online - so you should be good! :)

Comment: I know! That is how I learned many of the programming languages that I know,(to a certain extent). I have been messing around with Swift and C along with C++ but I have to say python is my favorite. I also know a few others.